# SAS macro variable concatenation with text with single quotes

Tags: sas

I am using `PROC SQL`. 
Macro variable is `STUDY --- ENTERED VALUE AS CBYM`
I want output like ---   'CBYM$test'

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS
    SELECT OWNER, VIEW_NAME 
    FROM SYS.ALL_VIEWS
    WHERE OWNER IN ('"&STUDY"$TEST');
```

It is giving error. Please help me to get proper macro variable with text in single quotes in output.

Comment: try ("&Study.$test"), i guess doublequotations make your problem here, but can not test at the moment myself. The dot is for Sas to recognize the end of your macrovariable and normal quotations are enough.

Comment: ...or simply `OWNER EQ "&STUDY.$TEST"`; ?

Comment: OWNER EQ "&STUDY.$TEST";  is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First note that SAS doesn't care if you use single or double quotes for string literals.  So you could just use:

```
"&study$TEST"
```

If you are passing the code directly to a remote database that does care you could try using the `%BQUOTE()` macro function to allow resolution of macro variable reference inside of single quotes.

```
%bquote('&study$TEST')
```

If the macro quoting causes trouble then you can use the `%UNQUOTE()` macro function to remove it.

```
%unquote(%bquote('&study$TEST'))
```